# Macro: Transposing issue

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, transpose, vba

Wonder if someone can help me with this one

Using VBA, I have set up a macro which starts by transposing a pivot table into another sheet then touches up the data automatically into a tidy little list for users to set up in a database later.

Now after building it first time for the pivot table it worked a dream and gave me the results I wanted but whenever I update the pivot table and it changes its length, I began to start having problems. Hopefully these screenshots will help:

[image]

You dont need to know the info on there but what the macro is expected to do here is transpose the entire pivot which can be done by either double clicking the cross section of the grand totals or right clicking on the cell and select show details of everything. (Highlighted in yellow)

As it stands at the moment the code for getting that cell is set to is:

```
Range("AA65").Select
Selection.ShowDetail = True
```

This is where I realized that it is fixed (At the moment to the place highlighted in red) and I have no idea how I can resolve it by making the macro adapt to varying lengths of the pivot table so that it can transpose all of the contents within it. If it helps, the grand total will always be on that particular row its just the column where it ends up that changes.

Is there a way for me to create a code where I can always pick up that Grand Total cell in the pivot no matter how many columns it stretches out to?

Thank you for reading and I hope to get feedback soon :)

Kind Regards

Zoe

Comment: To get the last used column, do a 
Activesheet.Cells(rnum, Columns.Count).end(xltoleft).Column, where rnum is the rownumber.

To get the last used row, do a Activesheet.Cells(Rows.Count,cnum).end(xlup).Row, where cnum is the columnnumber.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for instance

```
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
    .Cells(.Cells.Count).ShowDetail = True
   End With
```

Comment: And there you have it, tested and works perfectly and back to normality ^_^ thank you very much Josie you have saved me a lot of time :)